# Sort and combine elements to be unique

Tags: swift

I have a bunch of tokens stored in `combinedCoinsFromAllWalles` and I'm sorting them by who contains the largest monetary value like this:

```
let sortedCoins = combinedCoinsFromAllWalles.sorted() { Double($0.token!.quote!) > Double($1.token!.quote!) }
```

The problem is that some tokens are repeated by name, for example, on that sorting I could have 2 tokens with the same name on `$0.token!.name`

What would be the most efficient way to also combine those similar tokens and add their value? Something like this:

```
token A (named BTC)
token B (named BTC)
token C (named ETH)
```

I want to sum token A and B quote (`$0.token!.quote! + $0.token!.quote!`)  while filtering.

How do I do that in the most efficient way?

Comment: What is the expected result, two elements where one is a new one created from A + B? You say filtering at the end but I suppose you meant sorting?

Comment: You could use `Dictionary.grouping(by:_:)`, and a reduce on the values to combine them, then you can sort them.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, let me give it a try, but I think I would still need to iterate twice :/ @Larme

Comment: I grouped it like this: `let groupByCategory = Dictionary(grouping: combinedCoinsFromAllWalles) { (tokenId) -> String in
            return tokenId.coinGeckoId
        }` but how do I include now that dic. in the sorting? @Larme

Comment: Category? I though you were trying to combine the same with name? Now, you should have a `[SomeId: [YourClass]]`, you can use a `mapValues()`, to combine `[YourClass]` into one (and sum their values). Then, you need to sort.

Comment: I think I did it wrong then, yes I'm trying to combine the same with name, I'm using `tokenId.coinGeckoId` because those are the name. Is that the wrong approach to do it? I want all with the same `coinGeckoId` combined so I need to do some math to sum their values, is the approach I did wrong? @Larme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That first sort in your example is a waste since you have not combined all the different sources for similar coins first and the order may then change.

You should:

1. Aggregate coin values
2. Sort by desired order

One simple way to do this would be to create a dictionary, adding new coins or summing totals as you iterate through your data. Then convert the dictionary back to an array and sort how you would like.

Ex:

```
var dict: [String: Float] = []
for each in combinedCoinsFromAllWalles {
    if dict.contains(each.token) {
        dict[each.token] += each.quote
    }else{
        dict[each.token] = each.quote
    }
}

let sortedCoinValueArray = dict.sorted(by: $0.1 < $1.1)
```

The resulting array is an array of key-value pairs, so you may iterate over it like this:

```
for (key, value) in sortedCoinValueArray {
    print("${key}:   ${value}"
}
```

Comment: better to use the tuple element name for better readability `sorted(by: {$0.value < $1.value})`. Note that you forget the closure. Your syntax for sorting is wrong. Btw Xcode 13 has a generic structure called `KeyPathComparator` exactly for this purpose. `sorted(using: KeyPathComparator(\.value))`